# How to override object property value by index?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created an object that contains properties with empty values. I would like to access these properties by index and override their values. How can I do this ?

```
GetAllData: function(){
    var jobPayments = $("#table1 tbody tr");
    var jobPaymentsModels = [];
    jobPayments.each(function (idx, vl) {
        var jobPayment = {date:"",amount:0.0,method:"", reference:""};
        $(this).find("td input,select").each(function (idx, vl) {
            jobPayment[idx] = vl.value;
        });
        jobPaymentsModels.push(jobPayment);
    });
    return jobPaymentsModels;
}
```

Comment: Okay does that mean I will need to ignore accessing properties via index as its bad idea rather I should access them by name ?

Comment: @user16908948 - Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although object properties do have order now (which you'd need to use an "index" to access them), it's almost never a good idea to use that order, not least because its a bit complicated and depends on how the object is created.

Instead, I'd suggest having the **name** of the relevant object property on the `input`/`select` (if you don't already). Then you can use that name to set the property. Here I'm assuming you have `name="date"` etc. on the `input`/`select` elements:

```js
var jobPayment = {date: "", amount: 0.0, method: "", reference: ""};
$(this).find("td input, select").each(function (idx, vl) {
    const value = vl.name === "amount" ? parseFloat(vl.value) : vl.value;
    jobPayment[vl.name] = vl.value;
});
```

Details on that `jobPayment[vl.name]` notation in [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable).